# AJAX loader + SimpleCart

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

after a bit of searching I was unable to find a helpful post so...

My issue is that I use an ajax call to load some HTML into a lightbox:

```
function loadurl(str) {
try {
xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest(): newActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e) {
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = triggered;
xmlhttp.open("GET","productpage.php?b="+str);
xmlhttp.send();
}


//This is being triggered by
<a href="#lightcontent" title="$photoinfo" onClick="loadurl('$j')">Product Info</a>
```

The HTML I'm using works when accessed directly and I'm able to add/remove things from the cart, but when it's loaded into the lightbox via the code above, none of the simpleCart functions work. Anyone have any advice?

It seems like the eventListener in simpleCart.js isn't picking up events from the lightbox

Thanks!

EDIT:
The  portion is from a PHP file, and the $j just sticks a number into loadurl().
So, I'm loading (using 1 for example) productpage.php?b=1 into the #lightcontent div.

```
<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem" id="simpleCart">
<img src="{$glr}1/$mainphoto/Info/name.jpg"id="prodInfo">
 <img src="{$glr}ppimages/sizeqty.jpg" id="sizeqty">
 <img src="{$glr}1/$mainphoto/Info/size.jpg" id="prodsize">
 <img src="{$glr}ppimages/brandonmodelsize.jpg" id="modelsize">
    <h2 class="item_name" style="display:none">$photoTitle</h2>
    <select name="size" class="itemSize">
    <option value="medium">M</option>
    <option value="large">L</option>
    <option value="extralarge">XL</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="1" class="item_quantity" />
<span class="item_price">35.99</span>
<input type="button" class="item_add" value="add to cart" />
```

This is the code that is loaded into #lightcontent. SimpleCart is supposed to watch for any clicks to the class "item_add". When productpage.php is loaded via loadurl(), javascript doesn't work in the div :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to reinitialize simplecart.js after dynamically loading the content into the lightbox.

Live and learn :]